# special characters in layout xml of Android project

Tags: android, xml, layout

I again have a problem with special characters. 
In this case it is in a res\layout\mylayout.xml
When using characters like 'ó' and 'í' my project doesn't compile.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiosearchoptions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/searchtitleonly"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="buscar sólo en el título"
```

any hints ? thanks.

Comment: What compile error do you have? Have you tried to use strings.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use those characters you have to define a new `string` in your `strings.xml` file like this:

```
<string name="titulo">buscar sólo en el título</string>
```

And then, you add it to the text property of your `RadioButton` like this:

```
android:text="@string/titulo"
```

Comment: Perfect I'll try this. This also matches better into my concept having all language strings at one place. Thanks a lot. Is it also possible to have one layout.xml and a lot of strings with different languages ? Howto do this ?

Comment: Check this for multiple languages: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 0):

Save the file in the same encoding (utf-8) you declare in the `?xml` header. If you save in some other encoding, there may be octet sequences that are not valid utf-8.